# MS ACCESS How to drop a column with primary key

Tags: ms-access

I want to drop a column from  table in access which is the primary key.
how can i write a query for this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the primary key index on the table first in one query:

```
DROP INDEX PrimaryKey ON Table1
```

Then you can remove the column in a second query:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN id
```

Comment: i am getting an error message no such index primarykey on table1

Comment: You need to remove any relationship the table is participating in before your remove the PK.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: Don't you rather mean "You need to remove any relationship the PK is participating in before your remove the PK"? A SQL foreign key can reference a UNIQUE constraint that is not a PRIMARY KEY. A MS Access 'relationship' doesn't even require a unique constraint (don't believe the message you see when you try to save a table without a PK created via the designer, it lies,it lies).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the index in a number of ways.

```
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set RS = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema _
        (12, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, "Table1")) ''12=adSchemaIndexes
    RS.Filter = "PRIMARY_KEY = True"
    If Not RS.EOF Then
        Debug.Print RS.Fields("Index_Name")
    End If
End Sub
```

More here [What is the name of the violating unique index constraint in dao / ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649049/what-is-the-name-of-the-violating-unique-index-constraint-in-dao-ms-access)