# What is the name of the violating unique index constraint in dao / ms-access

Tags: ms-access, dao

I am trying to insert a record into a table with DAO (within MS-Access) and doing so, I receive an Error 3022 (which indicates that a unique index is violated). The error is correct since in fact the tried-to-insert record has a value which is already found in the table.

Now, I'd like to find out the name of the violated unique index. Does someone have a clue how I'd get this?

Thanks for any pointer
René

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to get that information, as the DAO error object doesn't return the exact constraint/index that is being violated (at least, so far as I know). I know exactly what you're going through as I've had inserts throw the error, and then I had to manually figure out which column was causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks David for confirming my suspicion. At least I know that others are having the same problem as I do.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes:

```
Sub WithADO()
''Reference: Microsoft ADO Ext x.x For DLL and Security
Dim catTables As ADOX.Catalog
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ndx As Object

Set catTables = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbfile = "C:\Docs\LTD.mdb"

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & dbfile & ";"

Set catTables.ActiveConnection = cn

For Each ndx In catTables.Tables("Table1").Indexes
    strlist = ndx.Name & " " & ndx.Properties("Primary Key") & vbCrLf & strlist
Next
MsgBox strlist

Set catTables = Nothing

End Sub

Sub WithDAO()
''Reference: Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim ndx As Object

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Table1")

For Each ndx In tdf.Indexes

    If ndx.Primary = True Then
        MsgBox ndx.Name
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

You could also use schemas.