# Syntax Error While Dropping the Primary key

Tags: ms-access, ddl

There is topic on StackOverflow: [Remove Primary Key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111291/remove-primary-key-in-mysql/52607740?noredirect=1#comment92149430_52607740)
Where it is described how to unassigned primary key from table's column. But this method did not work in my case.

I did use the code written in the topic above, for this extremely simple procedure, but still receive errors. Please help. Here is a code:

```
ALTER TABLE [BOM_V164_MK1A_PLM-000780855_02_D02102018_T10:50:56] 
   DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Here is the error I get:

[image]

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: if you are using msaccess than check this out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648974/ms-access-how-to-drop-a-column-with-primary-key)

Comment: If Backend is MySQL, use a passthrough-query and back-ticks instead of square-brackets to surround table-name.

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648974/ms-access-how-to-drop-a-column-with-primary-key you gave me also does not work:      https://ibb.co/ekxrpK

Comment: You have to know the name of the index (not the column) that is used as the primary key (that is probably named like `[PK_BOM_V164_MK1A_PLM-000780855_02_D02102018_T10:50:56]`and drop that index from the table. Check the indexes window to get the index name.

Comment: Used this https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/20/ms-access-list-table-indexes/ function to find index.  After I found index, I dropped it easily. So basically everything is solved:) Many thank to everyone's help! Now I need to mark the question as solved, and as I am a new guy I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the index specifically:

```
ALTER TABLE [BOM_V164_MK1A_PLM-000780855_02_D02102018_T10:50:56] 
   DROP Constraint [PrimaryKey];
```

Comment: For dropping indexes, I prefer DROP INDEX _indexname_ ON _table_ over an alter table statement. Both work, but `DROP INDEX` immediately makes you realize you're dropping an index, `DROP CONSTRAINT` can be any constraint.

Comment: Sorry, but DROP INDEX also didn't work in my case:      https://ibb.co/ekxrpK         :(

Comment: Your original syntax seems not to be supported in Access. My syntax works - but, of course, only of you know the name of the primary key index which, in Access, typically is _PrimaryKey_.

Comment: "typically is PrimaryKey".... Unfortunately it does not work in my Access Aplication... I am extremely disappointed as I have a lot of much more difficult tasks and I can't do this little simple thing....(((((

Comment: As others have stated, you need to know what the index is called - try using the function listed here https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/20/ms-access-list-table-indexes/

Comment: @Minty: Yep, and then use DAO and the TableDef object to remove the index.

Comment: ALTER TABLE [BOM_V164_MK1A_PLM-000780855_02_D02102018_T10:50:56] 
   DROP Constraint [PrimaryKey];                                                               Works on my Home PC.
Does not work at work.
Tomorrow I will try to find out what is the Index name.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Used this https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/20/ms-access-list-table-indexes/ function to find index.  After I found index, I dropped it easily. So basically everything is solved:) Many thank to everyone's help! Now I need to mark the question as solved, and as I am a new guy I don't know how to do this...

Comment: Left of the answer, there should be a sign to mark if answered. Also, mark up the comment from @Minty (as I have done).